# THREE.DRACOLoader is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I import the all three js and draco modules the following:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

and when I try to create the DracoLoader :

```
var dracoLoader = new THREE.DRACOLoader();
```

I get the following error:

```
> THREE.DRACOLoader is not a constructor
```

Is there any problem with import or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

huh, there's no need for THREE. this module imports "THREE" internally.

```
var dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
```

is working well...